# WPF garbage collection for a complex listview

Tags: wpf, data-binding

In perhaps a case of newbie overreach, I'm building a complex control (using WPF C#. see pic) in which automatic garbage collection does not seem to do as well as it could: I can get better memory use if I force a manual gc. I'm not sure if I should worry about it.

[image: the interface]

The `ListView` displaying "SectionList" is using a fair bit of memory (perhaps 100MB), as one would expect with all those controls. It's a `ListView` bound to an `ObservableCollection` of "sections" (e.g. "Math 125") (typically around 50 or so)  a property of a semester object. If I dynamically change the semester to another with similar content (thus binding the listview to a different observable collection of sections) I notice memory usage going up by about 100MB, even after some auto garbage collection. It doesn't seem to be a memory leak, as *if I manually force gc I can more or less recover the 100MB*.

I've experimented with various virtualization options on the listview e.g. setting IsVirtualizing=true/false, using recycling mode etc. Nothing seems to make much of a difference. There seems to be way more garbage available for pickup than the automatic collector sees and disposes. I know there's garbage there because a manual gc.Collect() collects it. All in all if I force gc from time to time I can keep memory usage of the whole app at around 300MB, but not if I don't.

The question is what might be going on here that the garbage pickup is being missed?

(Or do I completely misunderstand the issues at hand here?)

Answer (score 0):

> I can get better memory use if I force a manual gc. I'm not sure if I should worry about it...It doesn't seem to be a memory leak, as if I manually force gc I can more or less recover the 100MB.

If you don't have a memory leak somwhere in your code, you have nothing to worry about really.

This is the nature of nondeterministic garbage collection, i.e. you don't know and you cannot control when the GC returns memory to the operating system. As long as you don't introduce memory leaks that prevent the GC from doing its job propertly, you should be fine.

If memory usage is a hard requirement or if object lifetime may cause side effects in your application, using a managed runtime such as .NET is probably not the best option after all.

Comment: Thanks. Am I correct then that if the manual GC is clearing a bunch of memory, then that memory was not the result of a memory leak?

Comment: Yes. If there is a memory leak, the GC cannot collect it.